# Why am I getting different angles between the vectors in these two different processes?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, solution-verification, vectors

*This question came in the Dhaka University admission exam 2007-08*

**Question:**

Two vectors $\vec{P}=\hat{i}+2\hat{j}-2\hat{k}$ and $\vec{Q}=3\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+2\sqrt{3}\hat{k}$ are acting at a point at right angles. What is the direction of the resultant vector with respect to $\vec{P}$?

**Process 1:**

[image]

$$\tan\theta=\frac{|\vec{Q}|}{|\vec{P}|}$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{9+4+12}}{\sqrt{1+4+4}}$$

$$=\frac{5}{3}$$

Now,

$$\tan\theta=\frac{5}{3}$$

$$\theta=59.036^{\circ}$$

**Process 2:**

$$\vec{P}+\vec{Q}=\hat{i}+2\hat{j}-2\hat{k}+3\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+2\sqrt{3}\hat{k}$$

$$=4\hat{i}+4\hat{j}+(2\sqrt{3}-2)\hat{k}$$

Now,

$$(\vec{P}+\vec{Q}) \cdot \vec{P}$$

$$=\left(4\hat{i}+4\hat{j}+(2\sqrt{3}-2)\hat{k}\right)\cdot(\hat{i}+2\hat{j}-2\hat{k})$$

$$=4+8-2(2\sqrt{3}-2)$$

Now,

$$\cos\theta=\frac{(\vec{P}+\vec{Q})\cdot\vec{P}}{|\vec{P}+\vec{Q}||\vec{P}|}$$

$$=\frac{4+8-2(2\sqrt{3}-2)}{\sqrt{16+16+(2\sqrt{3}-2)^2}\sqrt{1+4+4}}$$

Now,

$$\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{4+8-2(2\sqrt{3}-2)}{\sqrt{16+16+(2\sqrt{3}-2)^2}\sqrt{1+4+4}}\right)$$

$$=58.83^{\circ}$$

**My question:**

1. Why am I getting different answers in processes 1 and 2?

Comment: There is something wrong.  Note that $\vec P\cdot \vec Q\ne0$ and hence $\vec P$ and $\vec Q$ are NOT orthogonal.

Comment: @MarkViola I rechecked the question. I didn't make any mistakes in copying. The question is flawed maybe....

Comment: Yup the question is flawed

Comment: Process 1 should work if the vectors are orthogonal, but the vectors are not orthogonal. Process 2 should work for any vectors. But since the exam writer was so careless about the orthogonality of the vectors, can we trust them to use the correct method when writing the answer key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The question is flawed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459098/why-am-i-getting-different-angles-between-the-vectors-in-these-two-different-pro?noredirect=1#comment9341156_4459098)

[As said by @DavidK,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459098/why-am-i-getting-different-angles-between-the-vectors-in-these-two-different-pro?noredirect=1#comment9341197_4459098)

> Process 1 should work if the vectors are orthogonal, but the vectors
> are not orthogonal. Process 2 should work for any vectors.